Having two user.signinkey on git config
I want to make commits to my repo using vs code but when I run git commit -m "message" I get this error
gpg: skipped "F1F0....": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

When I go to git bash and run git config --global --list I get this result:
core.editor="C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" --wait
user.email=example@gmail.com
user.signinkey=7669...
user.name=name
user.singinkey=F1F0....
user.signingkey=F1F0....
commit.gpgsign=true
safe.directory=C:/flutter/projects/projectname
gpg.program=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe
tag.gpgsign=true

I guess the error is because I have two times the same key and an extra. When I try to remove the 7669.. key it say not found. Also I noticed that I have a typo and I write singinkey = F1F0... the first time. My question is how can I remove from user.signinkey the two wrong keys: user.signinkey=7669... and user.singinkey=F1F0.... so that when I run git config I get only the correct user.signinkey which I have told github that it is the default key that it should use for commits.

signin != signing != singin. Unknown keys are ignored by Git.

git config --unset removes a config key. --unset-all removes all lines with this config key.
But the problem is not that you have typos in certain config keys, since these are ignored anyway. Your error is:
gpg: skipped "F1F0....": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key

Which means that you are missing the private part of your F1F0... GPG key. Add the private part with the correct permissions to your file system and you should be able to sign your commits again.

how can i add the private part? Do you know some video tutorial that i can watch?

@ShadySheen you have to find it (it had to exist before!). A GPG key has two parts, the private and the public part. The GnuPG docs are a good starting point. If you can't recover the private key, it might be easier to create a new key pair and use that going forward.
